# what is the type of functional component with generic type using compound components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have a compound component with three children and I need to declare the type of each child. all children are working fine except one with generic type always returns an error that expects 0 arguments and got 1.
[image]

this is the type I want to change
[image]

this is the error message that appears when I use the component

this is the component itself

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import { SelectInputI } from '../models'

    export function SelectInput<T>({
      value: inputValue,
      onChange: onInputChange,
      onBlur,
      getSelectValue,
      error,
      name,
      handleOptionLabel,
      handleOptionValue,
      options,
      placeholder,
    }: SelectInputI<T>) {
      return (
        <>
          <Select<T>
            name={name}
            defaultValue={inputValue}
            value={inputValue}
            isSearchable
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChange={(e: any) => {
              onInputChange(name, () => getSelectValue())(e)
            }}
            getOptionLabel={handleOptionLabel}
            getOptionValue={handleOptionValue}
            options={options}
            onBlur={onBlur}
          />
          {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </>
      )
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the SelectInput component

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It would appear that `NewSearch.SelectInput` is not generic. Without actual code to debug, there isn't much more we can tell you than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you resolve `React.FC<SelectInputI<any>>` then it is not a generic type.

Also, `React.FC` can't be made to be generic at call time, which is [one of many reasons you should not be using it.](https://medium.com/raccoons-group/why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-react-fc-to-type-your-react-components-37ca1243dd13)

You are basically doing this:

```
type Generic<T> = { value: T }
type A = Generic<any>
type B = A<{ test: boolean }> // Type 'A' is not generic.(2315)
```

What you need to do is this:

```
type Generic<T> = { value: T }
type A<T> = Generic<T> // type A is now generic
type B = A<{ test: boolean }> // fine
```

---

You omitted the `SelectInputI` type, so lets assume its this:

```
type SelectInputI<T> = {
    value: T
    onChange: (newValue: T) => void
}
```

And if you want a generic component that uses that type as props, and accepts a generic `value` type there, then it's type would be:

```
<T>(props: SelectInputI<T>) => JSX.Element
```

So if I stubbed out an object with that type:

```
declare const NewSearch: {
    SelectInput: <T>(props: SelectInputI<T>) => JSX.Element
}
```

Then it works as you expect it to.

```
const result = <NewSearch.SelectInput<{ label: string, value: string }>
    value={{ label: 'a', value: 'b' }}
    onChange={(newValue) => console.log(newValue)}
/>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAZSQBskMBJAOzAFcZWAeACoA+OAF44Ab1JwZcAG4pGXJAC44A6bIjsAwgAsU7AOaq4ACnZIA7gDVFytQICUYkXIjAAJqQC+5JAAekLBwmFzsGMDa9EwsvJw8gkJmUrLy9qbACTB2SkgANJoy2vqGJmraHNwwpcYFab5qDMxs2fzCLqmyRDBcUOxwfEJ8APRCvuSeLIwoRHBo2gDO8ABy1gyzaHpqXTLNcVU8aklmYDhgi02xrdXtQi6iIgBSdAAaAHQAoswgSOwwE1IC3YyzgREWXEY8HEfDWVg2UC2732N0SEjgMwARkw1MsoFkjPl0nlcTB8cY4D5xmkFHlRBJ0VicQQUPgibSHARMfhKX40iUDHV6RZrLllA8RMDFhBmO9GBAjCLbBknH4xkA)

Comment: thanks man everything is working fine and thanks a lot for the clarifications